# Справка > Привилегии > Редактировать Общие Сообщения

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, справка

В последнем предложении допущена ошибка.

> Кроме того, в авторском поле видно, **текст кого редакторов** в
>   процентном соотношении ближе всего к текущей версии сообщения.

Текст с ошибкой выделен жирным.

Полагаю должно быть так:

> Кроме того, в авторском поле видно, **текст кого *из* редакторов** в
>   процентном соотношении ближе всего к текущей версии сообщения.

Comment: Не могу найти этот текст в transifex.

Comment: @VladD http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki , в самом низу

Comment: Не, я имел в виду transifex, это сервер, на котором лежат строки с переводом английских текстов. (Замечание было для админов.)

Comment: @VladD, понял, не знал, я тут новичок, пока что)

Comment: Всё в порядке, спасибо за багрепорт! Стукнул админам в чате, они разберутся.

Comment: @VladD и вам спасибо

Comment: Спасибо за замечание! Обновил справку согласно ответу ниже.

Answer (score 2):

На мой взгляд, текст немножко не дотягивает до справочного центра. Ниже предлагаемые изменения. [Ссылка на текущую версию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki).

---

#### Что такое общие сообщения?

Общие сообщения - это такие сообщение, которые предназначены для того, чтобы любой участник сообщества мог внести улучшающую правку. Для редактирования таких сообщений не требуются дополнительные баллы репутации.

#### Когда стоит редактировать общие сообщения?

Общие сообщения предназначены для того, чтобы пользователи могли непрерывно редактировать их, поддерживая актуальность представленной информации, добавлять новую полезную информацию и улучшать качество сообщений в целом.

Пожалуйста, не стесняйтесь *вносить правки* в общие сообщения, если считаете, что можете добавить что-нибудь полезное.

#### Как редактировать общие сообщения?

Чтобы внести правку в общее сообщение, воспользуйтесь меню правок, расположенным под сообщением. Завершив редактирование, кратко, одним предложением, опишите суть своих изменений в поле сводки изменений.

#### Что произойдет после того, как я внесу правку в общее сообщение?

Все изменения, а также данные о тех, кто их внес, сохраняются в истории правок. Кроме того, в поле авторов видно, текст кого из редакторов в процентном соотношении ближе всего к текущей версии сообщения.