# Перевод термина «grace period» для редактирования сообщений

Tags: обсуждение, статус-завершено, локализация, термины

Давайте придумаем русский перевод для грейс-периода и [напишем пояснение](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3314/), что это такое. Будет удобно использовать его как штатный термин на сайте, — так же, как [общие ответы](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/948/208926).

Например, он нужен для перевода [сообщения об удалении правки](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3279/) (обсуждение и голосование за который идет прямо сейчас).

Пожалуйста, предлагайте варианты перевода вместе с контекстом. Поскольку есть две непересекающиеся области использования, мы вполне можем перевести термин по-разному в каждом из случаев.

---

#### Тексты на английском

- [описание тега `grace-period`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/grace-period/info)
- [FAQ How do edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/21789/330339)
- [пояснение к фразе `Edit removed during grace period`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/262894/6263942)
- [в каких случаях грейс-период закончится раньше, чем через 5 минут](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288559/6263942)

---

#### [Случаи использования термина](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/$/89248682?q=grace%20period)

Неизвестно, где используется:

> grace period

Относительно правки:

> [Edit removed during grace period]

Относительно конкурса:

> Your bounty on the question …
>
> #### $Title$
>
> … ended and will be auto-closed after the $AcceptGracePeriodHours$-hour grace period expires.

> Bounty Grace Period Started - $SiteName$

> Grace period ends in $timeLeft$

> Grace period has ended

Comment: Если не ошибаюсь, grace period есть также у вопросов, за которые назначена награда. С ним не будет пересечений?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov И, кажется, у комментариев тоже есть какое-то подобие грейс-периода. Надо проверить....

Comment: Создал отдельный вопрос, чтобы [составить статью об этом термине](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/3314/).

Comment: @NickVolynkin Думаю о том, что грейс-период конкурса - это период, в течение которого человек, объявивший конкурс, должен определиться с наградами. Т.е. - это совсем другая штука, которую надо переводить отдельно от грейс-периода для редактирования. (В справке она переведена как "[период щедрости](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)" :))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Предлагаю не делать буквальный перевод с английского, а заменить на понятие *свежей* правки.

Получатся тексты наподобие «свежая правка отменена», «правка считается свежей меньше пяти минут, если», «чтобы избежать появления больших списков мелких правок в истории версий, свежие правки от одного и того же пользователя сливаются в одну» и т. д.

Comment: А в том вопросе ответ запостить?

Comment: @Qwertiy: А о каком вопросе речь?

Comment: http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/3279/178988

Comment: Кстати, если есть тег, то его тоже надо перевести. А тут уже контекста нет...

Comment: Мне кажется, что понятие свежий никак не может относится к правке, так как свежесть всегда предполагает срок годности (актуальности). Что же получается? Если правка была принята, то она уже не свежая (не актуальная)?

Comment: @alexis031182: Ну, свежая означает «сделана менее 5 минут назад». Вроде не так плохо?

Comment: @VladD, не настаиваю. Возможно это как тот случай с аппетитом, который неприятным быть не может в принципе, он либо есть, либо его нет, но все желают непременно приятного.

Comment: @alexis031182: В любом случае, если вы придумаете хороший вариант, с удовольствием проголосую за него.

Comment: @VladD, спасибо. Вы легко разоружаете.

Comment: Это прекрасный вариант, если рассматривать его в отрыве от контекста. Но это перевод существительного прилагательным. Как его использовать на практике - непонятно.

Comment: @NickVolynkin: Это да, согласен. Я отвечал только на вопрос, с контекстом ответ будет другим.

Answer (score 2):

## Горячая правка

> горячая правка отменена
>
> правка считается горячей первые пять минут, если не ...
>
> чтобы не загромождать историю версий длинным списком мелких правок, горячие правки одного и того же пользователя объединяются в одну

Answer (score -2):

Голосование, вероятно, можно считать завершённым ввиду принципиального отрыва лидера, но тем не менее, полноты картины ради, хотелось бы оставить на суд ещё один вариант, который по субъективному мнению мог бы составить конкуренцию.

Оказывается, в русском языке понятие "грационный период" уже давно имплементировано. Соответственно, словосочетание "грационная правка" будет иметь такое же значение, что вкладывается в него и на английском, а именно - никакого отношения к программированию (если понимать дословно), но в тоже самое время по отдельным признакам в значении всеми принимается как то, что такое отношение есть, и эта ситуация полностью всех устраивает.

Использование "свежая", "горячая", иных похожих прилагательных отчасти помогают интуитивному пониманию истинного значения грационного периода, однако такое упрощение для восприятия не должно быть самоцелью. Уж если термин описывает существование чего-либо со множеством если и привязкой ко времени, то заменять его неконкретизирующими простыми словами, на мой взгляд, неправильно.

Соглашусь, слово грационный также не привносит ясности, если не имеется соответствующего набора знаний, обычно присущего всякого рода коммерческой деятельности, но если бы зарубежом было принято называть "зелёнкой" "лягушку", то и нам при переводе негоже подаваться в противоположную часть спектра. Хотя бы и по причине синхронизации значения понятий.

Таким образом, ответственность за незнание значения термина будет возложена на читателя, но не сообщество. Расписать само значение грационного периода в деталях и пояснительной форме не составит труда в том числе и простыми словами там, где это окажется необходимо.

Comment: Впервые слышу этот термин.

Comment: @Qwertiy, да я тоже только сегодня просветился, но оказывается есть.

Comment: Хороший термин упрощает восприятие, но само понятие он никак не может упростить. Чем сложнее понятие, тем важнее добиться интуитивного понимания. Термины - часть нашего интерфейса. Насколько прозрачны термины, настолько удобно  пользоваться сайтом. Поэтому термины должны "протирать запотевшее стекло", а не создавать новые сложности.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky, стремление к упрощению не всегда приводит к ожидаемому результату, поскольку ту же "горячую правку", например, лично я, не будучи информационно подготовленным, скорее ассоциирую с неким списком популярных топ-правок, нежели с теми, что всего лишь не получили подтверждения обдуманности намерения своих авторов. В чём профит от использования постороннего слова, если его дословное значение вообще никак не соответствует рассматриваемой ситуации с правками и всё равно требуются пояснения? Неужели так плохо использовать термин, который истинно предназначен для описания явления?

Comment: Мы собираем идеи перевода и голосуем за ту, что потребует меньше пояснений. Отзыв по конкретному варианту лучше писать в комментариях к этому варианту. Так удобнее ориентироваться в материале обсуждения.

Comment: @GlebKemarsky, мой комментарий был опубликован в качестве контраргумента тому, почему я не согласен с Вашим доводом. Приведён исключительно в рамках защиты собственного варианта.

Answer (score -3):

## Период неверсионируемого редактирования

Поскольку это сайт программистов, о системах контроля версий знают почти все, так что мне кажется, что термин будет достаточно понятен.

Comment: Длинновато. Попахивает немецким. Ну, знаете, der Периодневерсионируемогоредактирования.

Comment: @Discord, зато квадратиш, практиш, гут.

Comment: @Squidward: Versionskontrollenbedingtefreiheitsredakturperiode?

Comment: Слишком длинно, чтобы быть правдой. Это же кто-то мозг сломает точно