# Отмена голоса за ответ, который был быстро изменен

Tags: поддержка, правки

Имеется [ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/540861/176217) на вопрос. У этого ответа на текущий момент существует единственная (исходная) версия, т.е. редактирований как будто не было. Однако, когда я ставил ему "минус", выглядел он несколько иначе (более пустым). Вероятно, автор ответа успел изменить его в течение 5 минут ([время, пока правка не попадает в историю ревизий](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3295/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0-grace-period-%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%8F%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83)), но после того, как я его минусанул. Теперь же, ответ по факту изменен, и я хотел бы отозвать свой голос, но не тут-то было:

> Последний раз Вы голосовали за этот ответ 12 часов назад. Сейчас ваш голос блокирован до тех пор, пока ответ не будет отредактирован.

Налицо явная ошибка реализации.

Comment: В качестве воркэраунда, сделал тривиальную правку ответа, так что сейчас по идее можно исправить голос. Но баг, конечно, имеет место быть.

Comment: @VladD, судя по [этому логу](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/3268/revisions), Squidward  он же Discord он же Athari обладает более крутой магией быстро-правки под названием `[Правка удалена в течение номинации ]`. правил он этот ответ специально для того, чтобы убрать свой голос за него.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin: В этом приёме тёмной стороны Силы присутствие ощущаю я.