# Свежая правка не переведена полностью

Tags: дефект, статус-воспроизведено, локализация, нет-в-transifex

[`Grace period`](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3295/%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0-grace-period-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) всё же не переведен полностью. В частности английский текст доступен при попытке править [ревизию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/568289/revisions), помеченную как `[Cвежая правка отменена]`. После нажатия <kbd>править</kbd> наблюдается следующая картина:

[image: grace period]

В [Transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/89248682?q=Edit%20removed%20during%20grace%20period) проблемная строка значится переведенной, т.е. похоже, что она где-то продублирована и захардкожена.