# При правке вопроса в коде появились не мои изменения

Tags: поддержка, предлагаемые-правки, правки

Поправил [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/794706/phpquery-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80). Правка была [отклонена](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/241989).

Что удивило, и собственно суть вопроса: изменения в блоке кода были проведены не мной. Я не планировал ни изменять код, ни его форматировать. Поэтому, я не обратил внимания на содержимое кодового блока ни в начале правки, ни при ее завершении. Почитал про конфликтующие правки, но если это тот случай, то должен же быть какой-то след от другой правки. Но вопрос пока в первой редакции без каких либо изменений.

Могла ли мне в начале правки достаться временная редакция сообщения, которая при отклонении просто исчезла?

Comment: Первые пять минут история правок не пишется - вопрос "слишком свежий". Но по [таймлайну](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/794706/timeline) вроде уже вышел [грейс период](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3295/213987), хотя точно сказать нельзя.

Comment: @AK спасибо за ссылки, почитал,  примерно  понял как правки работают, но в данном случае осталось непонятным происхождение изменений в коде. Может стоило добавить метку дефект?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Это не дефект, это скорее race condition.

Вот, что происходит на самом деле:

- вы начинаете редактировать пост.
- автор начинает редактировать пост тоже.
- автор свой вопрос отредактировал и сохранил. Его изменения заключались в том, что он поменял имена переменных. Его изменения не создали отдельной revision (то есть не отразились в истории правок), потому что он это сделал в пределах 5 минут.
- а затем вы закончили редактировать и ваша правка отправилась в очередь проверки правок. Но ваша-то правка основывалась на оригинальном варианте вопроса!

Comment: Да, очень похоже на истину. Спасибо за ответ!  Вывод, лучше воздержаться от правки сообщений до истечения грейс периода.

Comment: @simpleCode Пожалуйста! После достижения [2000 очков репутации](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit), кстати говоря, вы сможете редактировать без очереди, и в случае чего откатывать свои неуместные правки, тогда можно и забыть об этом воздержании)

Answer (score -2):

Лучше вообще не лезть со своими правками в чужой вопрос. Независимо от репутации.
Ничего ведь не мешает писать ответы и комментарии.
У автора есть свое мнение, голова на плечах и пальцы на клаве.
По моему он и только он должен иметь право редактировать свое мнение и свои вопросы.

Кстати, минус здесь это за наличие собственного мнения принято ставить?

Comment: Ваш ответ подходит только для случая, когда правка меняет смысл вопроса. Если я могу улучшить качество вопроса своей правкой - я вношу правку. Обычно это правильные метки, исправление опечаток, форматирование кода, оформление в целом. Если я буду писать по каждому поводу комментарии - исправление вопроса займет намного больше времени, и автор вопроса может мой комментарий просто проигнорировать. В итоге качественный по сути, но плохо оформленный вопрос может быть заминусован.

Comment: Это понятно, если смысл не меняется, опечатки, форматирование - думаю это причесывание не вносит значительных изменений. Но правка автором своего вопроса думаю это только его прерогатива. Иначе редакторские правки с точки зрения каждого редактора, которых тут великое множество, могут исчисляться тысячами - у каждого редактора ведь свое мнение есть по поводу качества оформления вопроса или знаний великого и могучего.

Comment: @Rus _«правки могут исчисляться тысячами - у каждого свое мнение»_ Так то оно так.., но на практике «войны правок» встречаются очень редко (если всё же доходит до этого, то сообщение откатывается до редакции автора и блокируется). В целом, править чужие сообщения — хорошая практика, если они действительно становятся лучше.

Comment: @nomnoms12 улучшения вопроса, которыми "правители" оправдывают для себя свои правки есть навязывание своего мнения. Но учитывая то, что оказывается можно создавать вопросы, связывая их, и количество при этом не ограничено -  правка текстов чужих вопросов является работой. не оплачиваемой владельцем ресурса. Шутка ли, тысячи редакторов за баллы репутации шерстят весь появляющийся текст отделяя зёрна от плевел?